# Why is my discord bot spamming?

Tags: python, bots, discord, spam-prevention

I have previously posted on this same bot and got it working thanks to the people who responded. But, while it finally came to life and turned on, it started spamming messages for no apparent reason. I've looked over the code for typos and can't find any.
Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot (command_prefix = discord)

@client.event
async def on_ready() :
        print("Bepis machine fixed")

@client.event
   async def on_message(message) :
           if message.content == "bepis" :
                await client.send_message (message.channel, "bepis")



client.run("Censored Bot Token")
```

after @client.event is where i need help. also the bottom line if fine this time! turns out i had hit the space bar before the parenthesis and it didn't like that. Help is very appreciated so i can continue adding on to this awesome bot.

Comment: I guess the message you are sending triggers an other event that then results into sending a message again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending a message "bepis" in response to the first, *then every*, message "bepis" - presumably your first response will appear as an entry on the incoming feed which will trigger a second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not using proper formatting for my bot.
Whenever you say "bepis" in the discord server, the bot will see it and then say "bepis" back, as its intended to do, but, because of my improper formatting, the bot saw itself say "bepis" and responded as if someone else was saying "bepis".

Old lines:

```
if message.content == "bepis" :
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "bepis")
```

New lines:

```
if message.content.startswith('bepis'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "bepis")
```

So make sure you're using the right format if you're making a bot!

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything, "bepis" by the bot also startswith "bepis", the only thing changed is that the if now also excepts "bepis hi".

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to already know what the problem is, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50072783/6622817) you posted. But your solution is far from being able to solve the problem.

`on_message` is called whenever a new message is sent to anywhere accessible by the bot; therefore, when you type in "bepis" in discord, the bot replies with "bepis", then the message sent by the bot goes into `on_message`, which the bot re-replies "bepis", and so on...

The simple solution is to check if the message's author is any bot account, or if you want, if the message's author is your bot.

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bepis machine fixed")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # or `if message.author.bot:`   # which checks for any bot account
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == "bepis":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "bepis")

client.run("Token")
```

Note: I also fixed many of your other problems, such as multiple unused imports, another `Client`, and indentation.

And FYI, command_prefix is only used when command is being processed by a functional command. When you use on_message it has no use, which means you can set it to None.